# scroll behaviour smooth not working at all

Tags: html, css

I am wondering why my scroll smooth isn't working at all. I am not too sure why? I thought adding  `overflow-y: scroll; scroll-behavior: smooth;` will help but its not working. Here is my code:

```css
#container{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
.topTab{
bottom: 0;
position: fixed;
font-size: 25px;
color: white;
}
.pg{
  font-size: 100px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
}

a{
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class = "topTab">
  <li><a href="#1">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#2">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#3">3</a></li>
</div>

<div id = "container">
<div id = "1" class= "pg">1</div>
<div id = "2" class = "pg">2</div>
<div id = "3" class = "pg">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `html {scroll-behavior: smooth;}` should work fine here.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I was facing the same issue in modern Chrome (e.g. in version 88.0.4324.182) but I then enable the `smooth scrolling` flag using the below-mentioned URL :

```
chrome://flags/#smooth-scrolling
```

Comment: This also helped me, thanks!

Comment: enabled it where? what is a flag?

Comment: I don't think this's the way to go. We can't rely on users to do that...

Comment: Agree to @VinyMachado, this is only work at your own environment. If you going host your website on live it is not practical at all on asking user to perform this action. Just like some asking user to install chrome extension in order to make some function work.

Comment: Darn it, macos is not supported. I've been scratching me head over this, thank you!

Comment: @omar flags are experimantal features. You can find them by typing edge://flags (or chrome://flags) in adress bar

Answer (score 44):

you have to override the current auto scroll settings by putting !important into your css code.

````
*, html {

    scroll-behavior: smooth !important;
}
```
````

Comment: If I add this my scrollIntoView stops working at all, I can't figure out the issue.

Comment: That worked for me. What's really weird, is that I don't change the scroll behavior throughout my entire project. It would be interesting to know what affects the scroll behavior that needs `!important` to override it?

Comment: @Schnitzler Even I am wondering the same thing. This works on one website of mine without `!important` but the same line of code doesn't work on the other, without `!important`. I haven't overridden it anywhere.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using the !important declaration. This is a matter of CSS specificity. The solution that worked for me is to set a height on the #container element. I set the height to 100vh and that did the trick.

It's generally poor practice to rely immediately on !important in CSS as it creates edge cases that are hard to debug/refactor later.

Comment: Agree 100% with @buildpax. If I ever use `!important` at all I only use it as a _cheat mode_ when developing and certainly never in production. Otherwise you risk creating a rod for your own back. In this instance, I find `:root {scroll-behavior: smooth;}` is sufficient

Answer (score 15):

If adding scroll-behavior:smooth to html is not working, what worked for me is adding it to the body as well.

```
    html, body { 
      scroll-behavior: smooth
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. The key observation here is the style declaration needs to be applied not to the `body` element, but to the _root document element_ (referenced via `html` or `:root`). I rephrased the above as: `:root {scroll-behavior: smooth;}` and it works.

Answer (score 14):

In my case, it wasn't working because of my windows setting for best performance where I had disabled all animations. Turning it off did the required work
[Type Adjust the appearance and performance of Windows in the start menu to get this dialog box and enable all] [image: 1]

Comment: In my case, the particular option "Animate controls and elements inside windows" made the difference.

Comment: Omg, it turns out it's my windows settings that stops the animation....

Comment: same issue for me, thanks!

Comment: I have to say, this is one of the most legendary answers on SO - who would have thought this was an OS issue! good job mate, the Lord Jesus bless you :)

Answer (score 10):

- Try this one...

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#container{
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.topTab{
bottom: 0;
position: fixed;
font-size: 25px;
color: white;
}
.pg{
  font-size: 100px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
}

a{
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class = "topTab">
  <li><a href="#1">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#2">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#3">3</a></li>
</div>

<div id = "container">
<div id = "1" class= "pg">1</div>
<div id = "2" class = "pg">2</div>
<div id = "3" class = "pg">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

First ensure if your browser is compatible with the `scroll-behavior` or not.

[Check browser compatibility with `scroll-behavior`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scroll-behavior/)

If your browser is compatible with this property but still smooth scroll is not working
then this is not fault or error in code but you have to change a small setting of your browser.

If you are on chrome browser [go to URL "chrome://flags/"](https://chrome://flags/) depending upon your browser and press ctrl+f to open find dialogue-box  and search for smooth scrolling and simply enable it and re-launch browser to make changes.

Comment: As of right now the only browser on which this doesn't work is Safari.  And IE, but that should be no surprise to anyone.

Answer (score 4):

in case anyone has problems with this with Vue:

Adding

```
<style>
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
</style>
```

to **App.vue**
worked for me!

Answer (score 4):

I solved my problem with chrome by using this:

```
html:focus-within {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

More on the subject is posted on Css-tricks "Fixing Smooth Scrolling with Find-on-Page"

Comment: that worked for me, but I had to use !important

Answer (score 3):

While reading some of the answers got an idea to check if windows performance settings could be somehow related, and after switching to "adjust for best appearance" in System Properties > Performance Options scrolling became smooth.

Comment: Thank you so much, man. I've been looking for the same exact problem and none of the solutions worked, except this one. I didn't know system preferences might be the reason.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunatelly this will also stop working if your device "prefers-reduced-motion"...

I always thought overwriting stuff that's not "auto" by nature, is bad practice, but this seems to be a thing now.

Comment: For some reason I changed my OS to this reduced-motion thing. Good thing I found your answer that made me understand why. The solution is to run this in the browser (Chrome):
`chrome://flags/#smooth-scrolling `
And then select enable for it. I would suggest to change the OS to the default setting instead. As a developer you should use the most common setting in your work environment.

Answer (score 2):

I tried everything and nothing worked. Until i tried the last solution. Apparently windows 11 by default got "Animation effects" turned off. I didnt even know that. So i turned it on and everything started working. Tbh im not sure what is the relationship between animation parameter in windows settings and my browser. But apparently there's some kind of connection.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the solutions but got nowhere.

Biggest steps I took to fix it in my system were:

1. Restarting my frontend client.
2. Putting overflow-y: "**auto**"
3. Placing scroll-behavior : **smooth** in html outside container was not generating the desired result so I put it back inside the container and now it works

Note: I did these CSS changes for the parent container while doing same in the actual container also didn't help me.

```css
#container{
    overflow-y: auto;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a custom solution with the [easeOutSine](https://easings.net/#easeOutSine) function:

```js
function scrollTop (initial?: number) {
  if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop && document.documentElement.scrollTop > 10) {
    if (typeof initial === 'undefined') initial = document.documentElement.scrollTop;

    const progress = (initial - document.documentElement.scrollTop + 1)/initial;
    document.documentElement.scrollTo({top: initial*(1-easeOutSine(progress))});
    setTimeout(() => {
      scrollTop(initial);
    }, 10);
  }
}

function easeOutSine(x: number): number {
  return Math.sin((x * Math.PI) / 2);
}
```

since `smooth` isn't stable on my tests and I can't depend on the user enabling a flag.

You can tune the speed by changing the `setTimeout`'s second argument.

Answer (score 1):

Moin,
if you have a container, you need to set the scroll behavior separately.

```
#container {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

You can also use the following code to make the entire website scroll smoothly

```
* {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Paste the below link in your browser which you are going to use as the live server:
`chrome://flags/#smooth-scrolling`

Then, a new tab will open up and then you can enable the smooth scrolling option and relaunch the tab. For putting the smooth scrolling action into your website, you have to put the below code in your code editor:
`<html lang="en" style="scroll-behavior: smooth;" >`

Comment: Currently I don't see how your answer is different from the accepted, upvoted answer. Could you perhaps [edit] it?

Answer (score 0):

Just a little thing to check... I had the same issue but eventually realised / realized that I was spelling 'behaviour' the English way and not the American-English way. `scroll-behavior: smooth;`  should work on the `html` selector if correctly spelled. Though I appreciate that this was not the case for @James_Lee.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was really simple, but maybe someone else is making the same mistake, hence this answer.

For me I had changed my anchor links from
`<a href="#Home">`
to
`<a href="index.html#Home">`

The anchor links behavior was indeed smooth scrolling within my IDE's server's preview browser as well as locally in my browsers.
However, once I published to Cloudflare Pages the smooth scrolling changed to jumping.

I changed the anchor link back to
`<a href="#Home">`,
which brought smooth scrolling back to my staging site on Cloudflare Pages.

Answer (score 0):

There's one solution that I use in all my projects and works all the time and only requires CSS:

```
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

html {
  --scroll-behavior: smooth !important;
  scroll-behavior: smooth !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I had to turn on `settings` - `easy operations` - `show animation in Windows` in Windows 10.
(Check this setting if the mouse wheel scrolling is not smooth to begin with, regardless of the `scroll-behavior` in the CSS.)