# How do I make an HTML Page scroll smoothly one visible page at a time?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a webpage which will scroll one page at a time, the idea being that a  of class page will have a minimum size of 100% (i.e. the visible size of the browser window) and conceptually be a web page. When the user attempts to scroll past the bottom (or top) of the conceptual page the browser will smoothly scroll and snap to the top of the next  (page) (or the bottom of the previous one, if applicable).

Left and right scroll should be available still for a to implement a similar gallery function in one or more of those divs.

So far, I've tried the following (which doesn't work, of course, which is why I'm asking for advice here!)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="Test3">
<head>
    <title>Test3</title>
    <meta name="generator" content="BBEdit 13.5" />
    <style>
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}


#pages {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  overflow-y: scroll;
/*  display: flex; */
}

.page {
   scroll-snap-align: center;
   height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="pages">
<div class="page">Hello</div>
<div class="page">Goodbye</div>
<div class="page">What</div>
<div class="page">When</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

In this case, not all of the required functionality has been implemented.  It's a first pass at solving the problem. In this case, I'd expect the div to be fixed to the window size (which will need to be fixed), and I'd expect that scrolling would smoothly snap to the next div so that only one word would be shown on screen at any one time.

The idea is that that should work correctly on all modern web browsers, regardless of whether they're on phones, tablets, laptops or desktops.

Does anyone have any thoughts on what I've done wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scroll behaviour smooth not working at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62098093/scroll-behaviour-smooth-not-working-at-all)

Comment: That isn't what I'm looking for - when I try that, it just scrolls normally. I want a scroll past the bottom of the div to cause the next div to snap to the top of the screen - so nothing of the previous div is visible.  Sure, I want to see the previous div scrolling away fast and smooth, but once the scroll completes it should be like a freshly loaded page - albeit one that you can scroll up and down to get to the next and previous pages.